# Identify offset of a value in numpy

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

Given a flatten NxN array in numpy, I'd like to find the minimum value, and its offset in the array. I've managed to find the minimum value, but is it possible to identify the offset (which row and which column)?

In the example below, a = 0.5, how can I know if it is 0.5 from [1,0], or [2,1]?

```
from numpy import *

value = 0
NUM_NODE = 5
EDGE = array(zeros((NUM_NODE, NUM_NODE)))
EDGE = [[ 0.,          0.,          0.,          0.,          0.        ],
    [ 0.5,         0.,          0.,          0.,          0.        ],
    [ 1.,          0.5,         0.,          0.,          0.        ],
    [ 1.41421356,  1.11803399,  1.,          0.,          0.        ],
    [ 1.,          1.11803399,  1.41421356,  1.,          0.        ]]

a = reshape(EDGE, NUM_NODE*NUM_NODE)
print min(filter(lambda x : x > value, a))
```

Comment: Both of the 0.5's from [1, 0] and [2, 1] is minimum. Are you looking for the first position or last position?

Comment: is it possible to list all offset with this value?

Comment: You can't, with built-in `min` function, but you can easily write a loop to do it. Adding it to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> edge = np.array(EDGE) 
>>> edge[edge > 0].min()
0.5
>>> np.where(edge == edge[edge > 0].min())
(array([1, 2]), array([0, 1]))
```

which gives the `x` coordinates and the `y` coordinates which hit the minimum value separately.  If you want to combine them, there are lots of ways, e.g.

```
>>> np.array(np.where(edge == edge[edge > 0].min())).T
array([[1, 0],
       [2, 1]])
```

---

A few asides: `from numpy import *` is a bad habit because that replaces some built-in functions with numpy's versions which work differently, and in some cases have the opposite results; ALLCAPS variable names are usually only given to constants; and your

```
 EDGE = array(zeros((NUM_NODE, NUM_NODE)))
```

line doesn't do anything, because your `EDGE = [[ 0., ... etc` line immediately makes a new `list` and binds EDGE to it instead.  You made an array and threw it away.  There's also no need to call `array` here; `zeros` already returns an array.

Comment: I've coded all my way to solve this problem, but ended up here knowing that it takes only a few lines of codes for Python to do this! Thanks for the asides, esp. the side effect of from numpy import *, I didnt know that.

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.ndenumerate` will enumerate over the array(by the way, you shouldn't lose position information with reshaping).

```
In [43]: a = array(EDGE)

In [44]: a
Out[44]: 
array([[ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.5       ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  0.5       ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 1.41421356,  1.11803399,  1.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 1.        ,  1.11803399,  1.41421356,  1.        ,  0.        ]])

In [45]: min((i for i in ndenumerate(a) if i[1] > 0), key=lambda i: i[1])
Out[45]: ((1, 0), 0.5)
```

Or you can do it with the old way if you want every occurence:

```
In [11]: m, ms = float("inf"), []

In [12]: for pos, i in ndenumerate(a):
   ....:     if not i: continue
   ....:     if i < m: 
   ....:         m, ms = i, [pos]
   ....:     elif i == m:
   ....:         ms.append(pos)
   ....:         

In [13]: ms
Out[13]: [(1, 0), (2, 1)]
```

Comment: It would be sufficient to just return the first offset. But I would like to know if it is possible to list all offset which has the same min value?